# Не воспроизводится видео

Tags: java, android, videoview

Метод воспроизведения

```
  public  void play(String address){
        Uri path = Uri.parse(address);
        videoView.setVideoURI(path);
        videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(getContext()));

        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(myVideoViewCompletionListener);
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(MyVideoViewPreparedListener);
        videoView.setOnErrorListener(myVideoViewErrorListener);

        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();


    }
```

Вызываю

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video_stream, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this,view);
    getGetFragmentComponent().inject(this);
    videoStreamPresenter.attachView(this);
    videoView = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.video_view);

    play("https://ia800900.us.archive.org/24/items/TomThum_2013X/TomThum_2013X.mp4");
    return view;
}
```

Comment: и? Что происходит? Простите, но экстрасенсы только вчера ушли в отпуск. Какой кодек используется в видео? На какой версии Android?

Comment: Ничего не происходит. На всех версиях андроид

Comment: `Какой кодек используется в видео?`

Comment: И вы таки действительно проверили на **всех** версиях? Может еще и на всех устройствах?

Answer (score 1):

Информация о кодеке вашего видео, полученная при помощи `ffprobe`:

```
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=h264
codec_long_name=H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
profile=Main
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=1/50
codec_tag_string=avc1
codec_tag=0x31637661
width=854
height=480
coded_width=854
coded_height=480
has_b_frames=1
sample_aspect_ratio=1280:1281
display_aspect_ratio=16:9
pix_fmt=yuv420p
level=31
color_range=N/A
color_space=unknown
color_transfer=unknown
color_primaries=unknown
chroma_location=left
timecode=N/A
refs=1
is_avc=true
nal_length_size=4
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=25/1
avg_frame_rate=25/1
time_base=1/25
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=17533
duration=701.320000
bit_rate=856730
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=8
nb_frames=17533
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
TAG:creation_time=2013-03-14 19:23:12
TAG:language=und
TAG:handler_name=VideoHandler
[/STREAM]
```

Если посмотреть в [официальную документацию по поддерживаемым медиа форматам](https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core), то можно увидеть, что поддерживается

> H.264 AVC Baseline Profile (BP)

А ваше видео закодировано при помощи

> H.264 AVC Main Profile

Именно поэтому оно не обязано воспроизводиться ни на одном Android-устройстве. На некоторых возможно и будет, но это только из за того, что производитель добавил в прошивку этот кодек собственноручно.
Чтобы видео воспроизводилось, вам придется перекодировать его в один из поддерживаемых форматов.